# Direct access to MJPEG frame without decoding in OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, mjpeg

Working with OpenCV in Python, I ran into the problem of capturing an image directly from the camera for subsequent transmission via socket over UDP.
My project based on Raspberry Pi 4 B and USB camera which provide me MJPEG frames
But when I'm trying to use clear OpenCV **cv2.VideoCapture()** function with api=cv2.CAP_V4L2 and then **read()**

```
import cv2
import socket
import pickle


ip = "192.168.1.1"
port = 6666


src = 0 #Number of camera device which you can get from v4l2-ctl --list-devices

#Socket configuration with UDP. Size of package cover any 
# 60% quality MJPEG's from imencode or my camera on 1280x720
socketImg = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
socketImg.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 65535)

# This api will not work on Windows devices, be careful
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_V4L2)

# That's MJPG
fourCC = 1196444237
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourCC)


_, frame = cap.read()

#Encoding the frame to MJPEG with 60% quality
frameData = cv2.imencode(".jpg",
                        frame,
                        [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 60,
                         int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_PROGRESSIVE), 0,
                         int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_OPTIMIZE), 0])

#Creating byte-like object from frameData
framePackage = pickle.dumps(frameData)

socketImg.sendto(framePackage, (ip, port))
```

This operations take a lot of time and performance because we need to encode and decode image in each cycle (`cap.read()` have decoding inside anyway)

I tried to check some solution such as v4l2capture because they provide read_and_queue() without decoding but there is no documentation and I'm a little bit curious.
In OpenCV VideoCapture you can use V4L2 drivers for image capturing so you can work with V4L2 API directly from OpenCV without adding more legacy libs.
I tried to use some flags for VideoCapture stream:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)
```

But they did not give the desired result and `can.read()` continues to decode the image ignoring my attempts to fight it :(

I also checked some FFMPEG solutions but **my camera drivers doesn't support FFMPEG** (checked through `cv2.videoio_registry.getCameraBackends()` )

In this regard, I would like to ask if there are possibilities to capture an MJPEG image from a USB camera via OpenCV using the V4L2 API inside OpenCV so as to avoid decoding via cap.read() (where cv2.VideoCapture.retrieve() works under the hood)

Comment: [mre] is required. `src` is undefined. -- opencv is for computer vision, not for compressing and moving video. you're using the wrong library. instead use ffmpeg. it's also a library. use PyAV to access ffmpeg from python.

Comment: Have you profiled and measured the time to a) read a frame, b) encode a frame, c) pickle a frame and d) send a frame? Why are you pickling the frame anyway - it's not necessary.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I need to pickle the frame because I need to send byte-like, not a file through TCP. Anyway, I measured time from reading to sending and with  `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)` and without `cv2.imencode` it takes more time than just encoding decoding. I tested it with threading also and got the results around 60fps with encoding and decoding and around 30 fps with flags and without encoding decoding

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, sorry for MRE, changed it, with some comments. Using **PyAV**  sounds promising, I will run tests today and report the result

Comment: "my camera drivers doesn't support FFMPEG" is a silly statement. of course camera drivers don't support ffmpeg. those things are unrelated. what's even the goal? just read from the camera, compress the frames, and send them off. remember, UDP only fits 64 KB. you really shouldn't hack this. learn about video streaming properly.

Comment: You can get a bytes type from a Numpy array with `np.tobytes()`